# Как использовать Firebase, если проект с открытым исходным кодом?

Tags: база-данных, github, firebase, opensource

Есть проект с бд (сейчас это просто файл json), но я бы хотел перенести её на Firebase. Если проект просто залит на гитхаб, то бишь в нем видно все запросы и айди бд которые нужно сделать, как обезопасить бд в таком случае? Чтобы влиять на бд можно было только со страницы гх-пейдж, допустим, а любой человек склонировавший репозиторий или сделавший запрос через постмен условный, не мог её например дропнуть?
Также интересует теория вопроса, при открытом исходном коде есть ли риски выше уровня бд? Аккаунты и подобное, или имея запросы на руках можно влиять только на то что находится конкретно в бд firebase и только?

Comment: Не коммитить никакие ключи/токены/логины/пароли и прочие секреты в гит. Они должны браться из конфигов (эти конфиги естественно тоже не должны коммититься) или переменных окружения.

Comment: В гите их не будет, но в гите будет конкретная ссылка запроса, которую нужно сделать чтобы пришел ответ со всей БД. Как от этого обезопаситься?

Comment: Эту ссылку (или ее часть) тоже выносите в конфиг

Comment: А что за конфиг? Можешь скинуть материал какой-нибудь, статью\видео\название?

Comment: Любой конфиг. Хоть conf, хоть toml, хоть yaml - что угодно, с чем ваш язык умеет работать. Прямо руками пишите получение переменных из таких конфигов. Есть библиотеки, в которых можно описать переменные в .env файле, в коде обращаетесь к переменным в конфиге через имена переменных окружения, при отсутствии файла .env данные будут браться из переменных окружения, при наличии - из этого файла .env. Для python например есть модуль python-decouple. Для какой-нибудь java некоторые фреймворки типа quarcus умеют из коробки с такими файлами работать.